# MERN: Sendgrid returns unathorized when try registering a user

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, sendgrid

I have my user controller here, where I test to send an email whenever a user sign up.

```
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import generateToken from '../utility/generateToken.js'
import sendGridMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
import User from '../models/userModel.js'

sendGridMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

// @description   Register a new user
// @route         POST /api/users
// @access        Public
const registerUser = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, phone, role, password } = req.body
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })
    
    if(userExists){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('User already exist!')
    }

    // const user = await User.create({ 
    //     name,
    //     email,
    //     phone,
    //     role,
    //     password
    // })

    // if(user){
    //    res.status(201).json({
    //     _id: user._id,
    //     name: user.name,
    //     email: user.email,
    //     phone: user.phone,
    //     role: user.role,
    //     token: generateToken(user._id)
    //    })
    // } else {
    //    res.status(400)
    //    throw new Error('Invalid user data')
    // }

    const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: email,
        subject: `Iko account activation link`,
        html: `
           <h2>Please use the following link to activate your account</h2>
           <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/activate/${generateToken(name, email, password)}</p>
           <hr/>
           <p>This is email may contain sensitive information</p>
        `
    }

    const emailSent = await sendGridMail.send(emailData)

    if(emailSent){
        res.status(201).json({
              message: 'Email has been sent to ${email}. Follow the instruction to activate your account!'
        })
    }
 })
```

In postman when try to do a registration on `POST localhost/5000/api/users`:

```
{
  "name": "Night Smith",
  "email": "smithnightgmail.com",
  "phone": "55555555",
  "role": "regular",
  "password": "12345"
 }
```

It returns me this:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "stack": "Error: Unauthorized\n    at C:\\Users\\MERN\\Desktop\\MERN\\Route\\node_modules\\@sendgrid\\client\\src\\classes\\client.js:145:29\n    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
}
```

Note: I have the config on my .env file something like this:

```
NODE_ENV = development
PORT = 5000
CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://[i wont put it here]
SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.f8oUiOv-T1Sg7JcJohi2Dg.k
JWT_SECRET = 123456
JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION=OKaUvaxUugsmCm3UmzeK0
EMAIL_TO=rodelgrace@gmail.com
EMAIL_FROM=noreply@mern.com.us
JWT_RESET_PASSWORD=5WrQQUc828AytLkBZvV70E7ePsAB9u
```

Any idea what's causing this not to send the email confirmation? I place all the necessary details it needs.

Comment: please try to hide your environment details or set it dummy from your question for security purpose.

Comment: Hello, dont worry those are really dummy details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to have a verified `Single Sender` within SendGrid.

It must be a website email eg. `info@website.com`.

I think Gmails won't work.

Second, you need to put the `setApiKey` inside the register function:

```
// @description   Register a new user
// @route         POST /api/users
// @access        Public
const registerUser = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, phone, role, password } = req.body
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })
    
    if(userExists){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('User already exist!')
    }

    sendGridMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

    const emailData = {
        to: email,
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        subject: `Iko account activation link`,
        html: `
           <h2>Please use the following link to activate your account</h2>
           <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/auth/activate/${generateToken(name, email, password)}</p>
           <hr/>
           <p>This is email may contain sensitive information</p>
        `
    }

    const emailSent = await sgMail.send(emailData)

    if(emailSent){
        res.status(201).json({
              message: `Email has been sent to ${email}. Follow the instruction to activate your account!`
        })
    }


 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the key and authenticate to sendgrid using API Key before send email, look at the example here [@sendgrid/mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail#quick-start-hello-email),

```
import sendGridMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
sendGridMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

Comment: forgot to tell you I already incldued it `sendGridMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);`

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: console this key `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY` verify with your account. and check your sendgrid account settings as well.

Comment: It says:  API key does not start with "SG.".

Comment: It also returned this on postman `SENDGRID_API_KEY is not defined`

Comment: your environment file is not loaded yet have how you initialized .env file? have you used `require('dotenv').config();`?

Comment: I set that up on my server.js should I include it on my user controller

Comment: I tried to add it on this file `import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()` and now it returns forbidden

Comment: just add it in your server.js file, have you installed dotenv npm? if not please install https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: I already installed it on my module but still I am having this Unathorized error

Comment: Why can't you just put static key inside `sendGridMail.setApiKey("SG.f8oUiOv-T1Sg7JcJohi2Dg.k");` and test it is working or not. i am not sure probably the issue from sendgrid account or key.

Comment: So I tried this but it returned `Forbidden` this time. Really weird